# (Django) How to keep input values after form submit

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a view:

What I want is that whenever I submit a form (`if request.POST`) whether the form is valid or not, the values of the inputs do not disappear.

The inputs `event_form.description, event_form.event_type, event_form.dfkl_id` keep their values after clicking submit, but for some reason the value of the datetimepickers disappears.

How can I make the input value in datetimepickers not disappear when submitting the form?

Comment: post the form with its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the same form which has been validated, in order to return the same input content and form errors. Also relocate your `POST` request after the context data is defined *(After `data`)* Like so:

```py
if request.POST:
    event_form = EventForm(request.POST, instance=event)
    if event_form.is_valid():
        [... validate logic ...]
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/events')
    data.update({'event_form':event_form})
    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

Now if `event_form` does not validate, then it has a route to be returned.

Comment: Hi Lewis, it sounds promising, however I'm getting an `Exception Value: 
name 'args' is not defined` message. How should I define args?

Thank you.

Comment: As you haven't provided your `GET` section of the view, I cannot see how you have constructed your content data. Could you provide it so I can edit the answer.

Comment: Question edited with the full view, hope that helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI: I defined args like `args = {}` and then I'm getting this error message: `VariableDoesNotExist at /events/
Failed lookup for key [user_tz] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'event_form': <EventForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(title;description;dfkl_number;equipments;event_type;user;start_time;end_time;dfkl_id)>}]`

Comment: Ok cool, now move the whole `request.POST` section after `data` is defined. As you need the context data in the same view. I've edited my answer to reflect the change of variable from `args` --> `data`.